# losing quality after adding watermark to the picture

Tags: image, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm working on a website wich i haven't create/developed

Anyway users can upload image and when they do that , there's a function that create a duplicate of that image with a watermark

But the copy with the watermark has low quality and also it's size is much smaller than original image

I dont see anything lowering the quality , maybe it's how CI watermark works ?!

without watermark

```
http://img.akstube.ir/images/2013/05/DSC_0168_69_70_tonemapped.jpg
```

with watermark

```
http://img.akstube.ir/images/2013/05/irwm_DSC_0168_69_70_tonemapped.jpg
```

here is the function

```
function ir_watermark($file,$name='',$rebuild=FALSE)
{

  $ci = &get_instance();


  $pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
  $filename = $pathinfo['basename'];
  $path = $pathinfo['dirname'];
  $new_image = $path . '/irwm_'. $filename;
  $path_to_img = base_url(str_replace(base_path(),'',$new_image));


  if ($rebuild == FALSE)
  if (file_exists($new_image))
  {


  if ($ci->uri->segment(1) == 'test')
  echo "<img src='{$path_to_img}' />";

  return $path_to_img;
  }


  $config['source_image']   = $file;
  $config['new_image']  = $new_image;
  $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
  $config['wm_overlay_path'] = base_path('/files/transparent_bar.png');
  $config['wm_font_path'] = base_path('application/assets/view/tahomabd.ttf');
  $config['wm_font_size']   = '8';
  $config['wm_font_color'] = 'ffffff';
  $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
  $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
  $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '0';
  $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '0';

  $ci->image_lib->initialize($config); 
  $ci->image_lib->watermark(); 

  $config['new_image'] = $config['new_image'];
  $config['source_image']   = $config['new_image'];

  $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '10';
  $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '2';

  $config['wm_overlay_path'] = base_path('/files/akstube_logo6.png');
  $ci->image_lib->initialize($config); 
  $ci->image_lib->watermark(); 


  $config['wm_type'] = 'text';
  $config['wm_vrt_offset'] = '-3';

  $config['wm_text'] = 'Photo : ' . $name;
  $config['wm_text'] = strtoupper($config['wm_text']);

  $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
  $config['wm_hor_offset'] = '-50%';

  $ci->image_lib->initialize($config); 
  $ci->image_lib->watermark(); 


  if ($ci->uri->segment(1) == 'test')
  echo "<img src='{$path_to_img}' />";

  return $path_to_img;
}
```

WATERMARK IMAGE

```
http://akstube.ir/files/akstube_logo6.png
http://akstube.ir//files/transparent_bar.png
```

Comment: The JPEG image will be recompressed after adding the watermark. This process is lossy. `image_lib` uses a default quality of 90%, if not configured otherwise. But something seems to happen to the colors, too. Can you show us the watermark image file?

Comment: Dear max, 

regarding the size, I see that the two images have the same size. 

Regarding the quality, I don't see a loss of quality but I see a brightness increase. 

In any case to be sure about the quality add the option quality in the config:

$config['quality'] = '100%'


Of others options you can take a look here: 

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: @pixelistik THANK YOU , I'VE ADDED THE IMAGES AT THE END OF MY QUESTION , IM GOING TO TRY 100% QUALITY

Comment: @Madthew THERE'S A 600KB DIFFERENCE IN THE SIZE MAYBE YOU MISUNDERSTOOD WHAT I MEANT BY SIZE !:)

Comment: yes:-) in any case i've checked the two images. The watermarked one is made by: CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 and 72x72 dpi and NO EXIF data. The original one is: 240x240 dpi, with a lot of exif data including a thumbnail. Both are real jpeg.  The original use the ADOBE color profile while the Watermarked one the SRGB-BUILT in. did you try changing the quality?

Comment: @Madthew YEP IT'S DEFINITLY LOSING SOME PIXELS , EVEN ADDING QUALITY 100% DIDN'T HELP ... MAYBE I SHOULD USE PHP NATIVE FUNCTION